# Is there an easy way to create dropdown link that is text only without the button for bootstrap 4?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

Is there an easy way to create dropdown link that is text only without the button for bootstrap 4?

Or is the only way to create this is by removing the padding / button in CSS? I want the "Delivery" dropdown to look like the rest of the text.

I tried to google this and even looked on codepen but all I could find is just button dropdown menus.

[image]

```
<div class="dropdown">
              <button
                class="btn btn-light dropdown-toggle"
                type="button"
                id="dropdownMenuButton"
                data-toggle="dropdown"
                aria-haspopup="true"
                aria-expanded="false"
              >
                Delivery
              </button>
              <div
                class="dropdown-menu"
                aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton"
              >
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
              </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: Remove the Bootstrap class. Therefore no styling.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done by using an anchor tag instead of button tag like this:

```
          <a
            class=" dropdown-toggle"
            id="dropdownMenuButton"
            data-toggle="dropdown"
            aria-haspopup="true"
            aria-expanded="false"
          >
            Delivery
          </a>
          <div
            class="dropdown-menu"
            aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton"
          >
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
          </div>
        </div>
```